# Replace std::sort with boost::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, boost, std, preload

I would like to replace std::sort with boost::sort to compare the performance between them. A colleague recommended that I create a shared library with a re-definition of std::sort that calls boost:sort, and then simply use LD_PRELOAD to bring in the new shared library, and therefore override std:sort. Will this work? If so, can someone post an example of how to replace a stl function?

Comment: I would recommend against it - why not assign either std::sort of boost::sort into a `sort` function you have in order to test and then just call that function?

Comment: Well in principle for testing purposes ... what could go wrong? Though I would do the 'switching' of the `sort` functions via headers myself aswell.

Comment: `boost::sort` is implemented in terms of `std::sort` so it's a pointless exercise.

Answer (score 4):

To corroborate [Neil Kirk's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962990/replace-stdsort-with-boostsort#comment42464073_26962990) claim, we can take a look at the `boost/range/algorithm/sort.hpp` header. And `range::sort` is in fact implemented in terms of `std::sort`.

```
template<class RandomAccessRange>
inline RandomAccessRange& sort(RandomAccessRange& rng)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( RandomAccessRangeConcept<RandomAccessRange> ));
    std::sort(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng));
    return rng;
}

/// \overload
template<class RandomAccessRange>
inline const RandomAccessRange& sort(const RandomAccessRange& rng)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( RandomAccessRangeConcept<const RandomAccessRange> ));
    std::sort(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng));
    return rng;
}

/// \overload
template<class RandomAccessRange, class BinaryPredicate>
inline RandomAccessRange& sort(RandomAccessRange& rng, BinaryPredicate pred)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( RandomAccessRangeConcept<RandomAccessRange> ));
    std::sort(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng), pred);
    return rng;
}

/// \overload
template<class RandomAccessRange, class BinaryPredicate>
inline const RandomAccessRange& sort(const RandomAccessRange& rng, BinaryPredicate pred)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( RandomAccessRangeConcept<const RandomAccessRange> ));
    std::sort(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng), pred);
    return rng;
}
```

So there's no point in doing this. The page for [`range::sort`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html) also lists the complexity which mirrors the complexity for [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

Source: boost

> O(N log(N)) comparisons (both average and worst-case), where N is
>   distance(rng).

Source: cppreference

> O(N·log(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) comparisons on
>   average.  (until C++11)
>
> O(N·log(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) comparisons.    (since
>   C++11)

Comment: I like it when my claims are corroborated. It's a tickly feeling.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. 

 A formal review of the Sort library by Steven Ross was announced on the boost mailing list on Nov 9, 2014. So it's not in boost yet, and so I was mistaken. My goal is to experiment with these new sort algorithms which may or may make it into the boost library. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsort
http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost-announce